# Does a Prime Number $p_k$ Have a Prime Factorization (Where the Factorization Is $p_k$ Itself)?

Tags: terminology, prime-factorization

On one hand, we can think of the prime factorization of positive integer $n$ as representing $n$ by a product of prime numbers, each being smaller than $n$.  In that sense, a prime number $p_{k}$ cannot have a prime factorization, the "product" comprising only one number and that number not being smaller than the original number $p_{k}$.  On the other hand, we can think of the prime factorization of $n$ as the representation of $n$ by an expression where all numbers in the expression must be primes and where the only operators that may appear in the expression are those denoting multiplication.  In that more general sense, a prime number *does* have a prime factorization, where the number and its factorization are identical.  (Indeed, I have even seen arguments that the prime factorization of 1 exists and is equal to 1 itself, the justification being that a product of *no* factors is vacuously 1).

What is the consensus, if there is a consensus, on whether $p_k$ is its own prime factorization?  Will I be laughed out of the room if I refer to the prime factorization of a prime?

Comment: No, it is perfectly reasonable to say that, for $p$ prime, $p$ is its own factorisation. However I cannot guarantee you won't be laughed out. Few people can comprehend a product of a *single* factor (and even fewer can comprehend an *empty* product, always equal to $1$). So... tailor your exposition to the audience, or say it at your own peril.

Comment: As @Stinking Bishop says, it depends on the mathematical maturity of the audience. Some audiences will be confused if you say that $p$ is its own factorization, and some will be confused if you don't say that!

Comment: I agree that the prime factorization of a prime number consists of the prime itself, but I don't know why you would want to refer to it

Comment: Having said that, the whole theory can be re-told if the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic is stated as "Any natural number bigger than $1$ is *either* prime *or* can be uniquely written as a product of (not necessarily distinct) primes." In other words, start distinguishing cases in the statement, this will proliferate through the whole theory. It will superficially look different, but will not either bring or take away any fundamental conclusions.

Comment: If you want to say $p$ is its own factorization, you just have to remove that statement about "each being smaller than $n$" (which really plays no role).    To understand the "product of one prime" being that prime, as well as the product of $0$ primes being $1$, think of starting with $1$ and multiplying successively by each of the prime factors.  If there is one prime factor, you get that prime.  If there are no primes, you stay with $1$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, I have my reasons.  Specifically, I am writing an article in which I discuss a mathematical object founded on the generalized concept of prime factorization, and I do not wish to complicate my discussion by having to regard some instances of that object as prime factorizations and some not.

Comment: In the case $n=1$ , I would not speak of a "prime factorization" although mathematically it is valid. This is like "All of my children are chess grand masters" (sounds great, but I have no children). In the case of a single prime however, I think it makes sense to speak of an "already factored expression".